# bit operators from Deuces

Tags: python, python-3.x, bitwise-operators

So I downloaded Deuces, code for poker hand evaluations, and originally I think it was in Python 2, because all of the print statements had no parentheses. I fixed all of those, and everything seems to work, except this last part. Here is the code for it:

```
def get_lexographically_next_bit_sequence(self, bits):
    """
    Bit hack from here:
    http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation

    Generator even does this in poker order rank 
    so no need to sort when done! Perfect.
    """
    t = (bits | (bits - 1)) + 1 
    next = t | ((((t & -t) / (bits & -bits)) >> 1) - 1)  
    yield next
    while True:
        t = (next | (next - 1)) + 1 
        next = t | ((((t & -t) / (next & -next)) >> 1) - 1)
        yield next
```

I looked online and found that they are bit operators, but I dont understand why python doesnt recognize them. Do I have to import something, or are those operators not used in python 3

```
 File "/Volumes/PROJECTS/deuces/All_poker.py", line 709, in get_lexographically_next_bit_sequence
next = t | ((((t and -t) / (bits and -bits)) // 2) - 1)
```

TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'float' and 'float'

This is the error I get and the code can be found at https://github.com/vitamins/deuces/tree/8222a6505979886171b8a0c581ef667f13c5d165

It is the last portion of the lookup class

when I write

```
board = [ Card.new('Ah'), Card.new('Kd'), ('Jc') ]
hand = [ Card.new('Qs'),Card.new('Th')]
evaluator=Evaluator()
```

On that last line of code I get the error. All of the code can be found in the link

Comment: Could you tell us why error you're getting? At first glance I'm not seeing anything wrong with the code you posted.

Comment: You've not explained a problem. What *specifically* can we help you with?

Comment: I bet the source of your error is the semantic difference between `/` in Python 2 and 3. In Python 2, `/` is floor division, wheras in Python 3, it is true division, and will likely return a `float`, which will throw `TypeError`s with bitwise operators.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I really didn't steal your comment. :) I had to try my surmise to see, and then found your comment.

Comment: I meant, for a specific input to `get_lexographically_next_bit_sequence` what sequence of results would you expect to receive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was the / symbol, as the gentleman said above it is supposed to be for floor division, and quick fix and it works fine.

Answer (score 3):

In accord with Arrivillaga's comment I had just modified what you had posted to this.

```
def get_lexographically_next_bit_sequence(bits):
    """
    Bit hack from here:
    http://www-graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#NextBitPermutation

    Generator even does this in poker order rank 
    so no need to sort when done! Perfect.
    """
    t = (bits | (bits - 1)) + 1 
    next = t | ((((t & -t) // (bits & -bits)) >> 1) - 1)  
    yield next
    while True:
        t = (next | (next - 1)) + 1 
        next = t | ((((t & -t) // (next & -next)) >> 1) - 1)
        yield next

for i, g in enumerate(get_lexographically_next_bit_sequence(123)):
    print (g)
    if i > 10:
        break
```

Do these results seem reasonable?

```
125
126
159
175
183
187
189
190
207
215
219
221
```

Comment: No I dont get that

Comment: Would you please edit your question to give a sample input and output, and then leave a comment for me.

Comment: I just did, Bill Bell